# How to create an own bower-asset?

Tags: bower, gentelella

I need to create my own bower-asset with my fork of Gentelella Theme (ColorlibHQ/gentelella), because I need a light weight vendor version.

I've done  these following code on terminal:

```
bower init
```

and than I remove some package and  i have digit

```
bower prune
```

to purify from libraries not used.
Than I use

```
bower register myname-gentelella https://github.com/USERNAME/PACKAGENAME.git
```

But I don't see it to https://bower.io/search/, and it seems don't exist if I call from another application.

Comment: whats your git repo address?

Comment: Have you checked all the requirements for registering a bower package? https://bower.io/docs/creating-packages/#register

Comment: Yes I've checked all requirements